# How to edit a single frame without affecting all frames of animation in Photoshop CS5?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, animation

I can't figure it out why this is happening.
I want to animate a logo frame by frame using Photoshop CS5 and everytime i change something in a frame, it changes all frames before until the moment i created a layer/shape. In result, all frames turn to be the same.

I'm thinking to use 4 layers and I would animate "interior" layer first and  "splashes" in the end.

My layers: 
4 - splashes (to edit) 
3 - interior (to edit) 
2 - vector smart object mask (lock) 
1 - background (lock)

Should I create a new layer for each new frame to resolve this problem?

Comment: @Luciano, I saw [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_9hdOUa-6JE) tutorial and i would like to know if i can edit frames in Photoshop CS5 or I must have Photoshop CC to do that.

Comment: yes you can. In the Adobe website (http://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/saving-exporting-video-animations.html) it says you need the Extended version for that.

Comment: Thank you @Luciano. However I've resolved this problem  with Photoshop CC trial. I will give a shot in the next time in Photoshop CS5.